# Can a solid Au nanoparticle rotate (i.e., spin) in a vacuum?

Tags: rotation

I think there are two cases, if it has an initial angular velocity, then it is supposed to rotate. If its initial angular velocity is zero, then the particle would not rotate. However, should a solid Au nanoparticle rotate in a vacuum?

Comment: Asking "should an Au nanoparticle rotate in a vacuum?" is like asking "can a pizza fly?". It can, if you throw it first.

Comment: Actually, when you get down to that scale, you must ask yourself what does rotation mean!! What happens if it's symmetrical under rotation?

Comment: May I understand in this way: if the angular momentum of  a particle is not zero, then it will rotate. @DumpsterDoofus

Comment: It looks like the particle rotates around an axis that crosses its central point. However, it is not perfectly symmetrical as atoms vibrates so that the shape of the particle changes a little. @Ali

Answer (score 1):

How nano? Above zero kelvin or its quantum ground state, a molecule will have populated rotational states (microwave transitions if dipolar or distorted so).  A gold atom is massive.  Where is the gold cluster size transition between a microscopic entity with quantum properties and a lump that classically sits there unless kicked?

Methane, ${CH_4}$, is a Greenhouse gas for its vibrational IR transitions.  Selection rules demand a dipole transition.  Point group ${T_d}$ is highly symmetric, a tetrahedron with carbon at its centroid.  Rotational distortion gives methane microwave (rotational) and IR (vibrational) spectra.

Comment: "How nano?" This is a good counterquestion! I'recommend not to answer any question which mentions "nano". Its so burdened with fashion and science-journalists sillyness.

Comment: Does it make a big difference if its diameter is 30 Angstrom or 100 Angstrom?